# What opera is Banner listening to in Avengers: Age of Ultron?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron, music-identification

In Avengers: Age of Ultron, at about timestamp 12:35, Banner is listening to some opera music. What is the name of the song he is listening to?

Comment: Green Day? Smashing Pumpkins?

Comment: I would have assumed anything by Verdi

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per the film's [soundtrack credits](https://www.soundtrack.net/movie/the-avengers-age-of-ultron/);

> [NORMA, ACT I: 'CASTA DIVA'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-TwMfgaDC8)
>
> Written by Vincenzio Bellini.
>
> Performed by Maria Callas / Coro Del Teatro Alla Scala, Milano/
> Orchestra Del Teatro Alla Scala, Milano / Tullio Serafin.
>
> Courtesy of Warner Classics.
>
> By arrangement with Warner Music Group Film & TV Licensing.